# Parity issue with personal.lockAccount() - Method Not Found Problem

Tags: parity

personal.lockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[0])

Error: Method not found

```
at web3.js:3104:20
at web3.js:6191:15
at web3.js:5004:36
at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Comment: There is no such method in the [personal module](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-personal-module).

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this.

```
web3.eth.personal.lockAccount(address,passphrase)
```